# QT Linux - QObject::connect & QHttp issue

Tags: qt, qobject

I have a problem. I'm writing a small application, which will fetch an image from a website and display it in a QT GUI application.

I use QHttp to do this. The code works if I execute it in main (before GUI is shown), but when I try to implement it, so that the code will run when I click on a button, it doesn't work.
Here's some of the code:

**downloader.h - The class that's responsible for creating connection and saving image**

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QHttp>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

class Downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Downloader(QObject *parent = 0);
    void getImageFromWeb(QString host, QString append);
signals:

public slots:
    void stateChanged(int state);
    void responseHeaderReceived(const QHttpResponseHeader &resp);
    void requestFinished(int id, bool error);
private:
    QHttp *http;
};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

**downloader.cpp - The implementation**

The case switches are added for debugging

```
#include "downloader.h"
#include <QApplication>

Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

void Downloader::getImageFromWeb(QString host, QString append)
{
    http = new QHttp(this);

    connect(http, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(stateChanged(int)));
    qDebug() << "Connect 1";
    connect(http, SIGNAL(responseHeaderReceived(QHttpResponseHeader)), this, SLOT(responseHeaderReceived(QHttpResponseHeader)));
    qDebug() << "Connect 2";
    connect(http, SIGNAL(requestFinished(int,bool)), this, SLOT(requestFinished(int,bool)));
    qDebug() << "Connect 3";

    http->setHost(host);
    http->get(append);
}

void Downloader::stateChanged(int state)
{
    switch(state)
    {
    case 0:
        qDebug() << "Unconnected";
        break;
    case 1:
        qDebug() << "Hhost Lookup";
        break;
    case 2:
        qDebug() << "Connection";
        break;
    case 3:
        qDebug() << "Sending";
        break;
    case 4:
        qDebug() << "Reading";
        break;
    case 5:
        qDebug() << "Connect";
        break;
    case 6:
        qDebug() << "Closing";
        break;
    }
}

void Downloader::responseHeaderReceived(const QHttpResponseHeader &resp)
{
    qDebug() << "Size" << resp.contentLength();
    qDebug() << "Type" << resp.contentType();
    qDebug() << "Status" << resp.statusCode();
}

void Downloader::requestFinished(int id, bool error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "OK";

        QFile *file = new QFile(QDir::currentPath() + "/image.png");
        if(file->open(QFile::Append))
        {
            file->write(http->readAll());
            file->flush();
            file->close();
        }

        delete file;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp - The code above works correctly if it is implemented like this**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <downloader.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Downloader getImage;
    getImage.getImageFromWeb("servlet.dmi.dk", "/byvejr/servlet/byvejr?by=8000&tabel=dag3_9");

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Instead of this, I would like the image to be fetched when I press a button in the program, so I tried this:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "downloader.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDir>

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Downloader getImage;
    getImage.getImageFromWeb("www.dmi.dk/", "/uploads/tx_dmidatastore/webservice/k/d/_/n/g/femdgn_dk.png");
}
```

This doesn't work. From the debugger I get:

```
Connect 1
Connect 2
Connect 3
```

When it works (when it's implemented in main.cpp) the debugger gives me something like:

```
Connect 1 
Connect 2 
Connect 3 
OK 
Connection 
Sending 
Reading 
Size 16282 
Type "image/png" 
Status 200 
Connect 
OK
```

So I guess this tells me that the connections are made, but nothing is being executed.

Any answer/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your getImage object is being descoped/destructed before it can do anything. Try creating a Downloader object as a member of MainWindow instead of inside the on_pushButton_clicked() function.

Comment: I tried to create a Downloader object and then just call the function getImage.getImageFromWeb(QString, QString) inside the on_pushButton_clicked().
That doesn't work either. The debugger gives me this instead though:
Connect 1 
Connect 2 
Connect 3 
OK 
Connection
ERROR!
Closing.

Thank you for your time anyway :)